# Sweave how can I write R code inside the latex table environment?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am working on Sweave now, when I want to use R code to describe one variable in the latex table.

It turns out that Sweave cannot read these R codes, the output is not the variable, instead, the output is the text form of all the code I write

Comment: What have you tried to do? If you are looking for a good guide to start working with Sweave then maybe look at http://pineda-krch.com/2011/01/17/the-joy-of-sweave/ or the Sweave manual.

Comment: Can you give us a sneak preview of the code you're using? Have you tried `<<tex = TRUE>>` in your code chunk?

Comment: Roman, is that tex=TRUE or results=tex ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want `\Sexpr{R expression}`; for example, this Sweave snippet

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
z <- exp(pi)
@

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  a & \Sexpr{z} \\
  b & \Sexpr{round(z,3)}  \\
\end{tabular}
```

becomes this when Sweaved (Swoven?)

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  a & 23.1406926327793 \\
  b & 23.141  \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: PS if my answer is correct you might want to edit the title of your question, as the "within the LaTeX tabular environment" part is irrelevant ...

Comment: I am glad to +1 your answer for more than just this but "Swoven" alone is worth it!